# Bizzare Issue With Java Timestamp

Tags: java, json, spring

I am working on an application which sends an object to a server for processing. The object is sent in JSON format using Spring.

My issue is that all the fields are passed correctly - EXCEPT for the Date variables. They show up as a completely different value, and I am stumped as to why.

Here is an abbreviated version of the object that is being passed:

```
public class TransactionParameters {

    public Date startDate;
    public Date endDate;
    public List<String> transactionCodes;
    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }
    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }
    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }
    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
    public List<String> getTransactionCodes() {
        return transactionCodes;
    }
    public void setTransactionCodes(List<String> transactionCodes) {
        this.transactionCodes = transactionCodes;
    }

}
```

Here is the JSON created:

```
{"transactionCodes":["195"],"startDate":1524456000000,"endDate":1524456000000}
```

Here is the client code:

```
String responseString =
restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:9080/app/transaction" 
+ "testUser123", transactionParameters, String.class);
```

Here is the server code:

```
@ApiOperation(value="Get Transactions for Customer")
@POST
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/customerAccountTransactions/{customerCode: [a-zA-Z0-9]+}")
@RequestMapping(value ="/transaction/{customerCode: [a-zA-Z0-9]+}", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiImplicitParams(@ApiImplicitParam(name = AUTHORIZATION, value = AUTHORIZATION, required = true, dataType = STRING, paramType = HEADER))
public Response getAccountTransactionsForCustomer(@PathVariable(CUSTOMER_CODE) @PathParam(CUSTOMER_CODE) final String customerCode, TransactionParameters transactionParameters) throws IntegrationException {
    LOGGER.info("getAccountTransactionsForCustomer()");
    Response response = null;

    try {
        final AccountTransactionsBean atb = getTransactions(customerCode, transactionParameters)
        response = ResponseBuilder.buildSuccessResponse(atb);
    } catch (final NotAuthorizedException nae) {
        response =  ResponseBuilder.buildNotAuthorizedResponse();
    }
    return response;
}
```

But here's my issue - When I put a breakpoint at where the client calls the endpoint, the date is correct.

[image]

However, the date is **wildly incorrect** as it enters the server's endpoint.

[image]

All the the other variables in the TransactionParameters bean are correct. I have also replicated this call using SOAP UI, to rule out any issues with the client, and the issue still persists.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: probably a time zone issue

Comment: I'm guessing a serialization issue. Please include the raw JSON.

Comment: I thought time zone as well @SharonBenAsher, but would that explain a 257,000,000 year difference?

Comment: @xtratic I posted JSON under the object.

Comment: @user1472409 It's serialized as a `long`, but not de-serialized from `long` properly.

Comment: Why isn't the date serialized in ISO 8601 format?

Comment: @xtratic Thanks for the help - the "TransactionParameters" object is the exact same on the client side as it is on the server side. Both use the java.util.Date class for their timestamps. Do you know what could be causing the serialization problems?

Comment: Can you check what is the raw JSON received in the server side?

Comment: I'm sure the JSON sent is the JSON recieved, unless there's something *very* weird going on...

Comment: It might have to do with the different hosts system clock resolutions. What happens if you run both on the same host, or do you already do that?

Comment: @daniu Both are running on the same host.

Comment: Dates are not part of the JSON data types. To transmit a date value, you need to establish a convention between sender and receiver as to how your encoding works. Just sending a long integer is not reliable. You could encode and decode it as a string in ISO-8601 format; just make sure you include the timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this issue is that Date and String are two different data types. When you are converting your Object to JSON, it is directly converting the date to String and in that process losing its essence.

In order to solve this, you need to tell the code that those particular fields are dates and thus, need to be retained as it is. You can do that by using annotations in your POJO:

Example:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
private Date changeTimestamp;
```

You can use the above syntax and then change the pattern as per your need.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "essence" is being lost when converting Date to String? Maybe with an example?

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer* admittedly I don't know much about Spring REST so I can only give you general pointers, but this really does seem like a de-serialization issue.

Some general things to consider:

1. Make sure the server and client have the same settings for serializing/de-serializing.
2. Make sure they are running the same versions of Spring REST and Jackson.
3. Set the JVM arg `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and run again to look at what is *really* being sent/recieved.

Being Spring REST this uses Jackson under the hood right?

Try explicitly annotating your dates and see if that helps:

```
public class TransactionParameters {
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    public Date startDate;
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    public Date endDate;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to either add or remove the milliseconds to get the conversion to work correctly. 000